# High quality alternatives to PDF

Tags: pdf

We are trying to figure out the best way to create a web service that delivers high quality text books to remote tablets and desktop clients. The books are copyrighted and sold to users so the delivery must be protected as much as possible against copy. The books' layout is very complicated, with lots of images, pictures, textures, tables, diagrams and the like. They are produced by InDesign in PDF format.

So far, our best guess is to store the PDF in single pages (a PDF per page) and scramble them with asymmetric keys, so all the decryption can be processed in memory with no temporary file generated.

Our concern is that PDF is a proprietary format and sometimes the file is too big (quality is an important concern for the client).

Is there any Open Source alternative to PDF, capable of delivering high quality, complicated layouts in smaller files?

Comment: you might want to have a look at DjVU - but PDF format is considered open now. What I am more concerned about is your copyright approach. Users will hate you, when scrolling through the pages is not fluent. And loading them one by one only that you prevent someone copying the book he really bought... might upset users

Comment: PDF is designed by Adobe I think, but anyone can create a reader or writer, so is it proprietary in the usual meaning of the phrase?

Comment: also i will just take screenshots, ocr it back and put in online for FREE.. and that in an automated fashion!! \o/ DRM is the worst choice, proven by the fact that it just created another problem for you.

Comment: @GungFoo then he will simply display green/yellow/red shiny glowing lines alternating at 15/frames a second... so you cant do that AAAAND also... epilespy

Comment: Let me remind you all that this is a technical forum, not a political meeting. Questions about DRM are perfectly valid here and you're free not to answer.

Comment: Do yo wish the purchaser to be able to store the book on their PC or tablet so that it can be read without an internet connection?

Comment: ChrisBD, it will be usable offline. Browseability is a prime concern, right. We have to do test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only way around this if it is to be viewable offline is to encrypt the document and issue licence keys for it to be viewable.

There are commercial packages that will allow you to do this enabling you to limit the licence to machine, user or time period.

Ultimately you can't stop people coming up with ingenious ways of copying it, just make it more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

You can use raster image with high quality as PDF alternative.